# Is there a website that lists all non standard python libraries?

Tags: python

I am new to python, I have started with pandas, but I am not sure where to find a complete list of all non standard libraries if I were faced with a problem that pandas could not solve.

I have tried python documentations, but could not find anything

Comment: https://pypi.org/ <- the website of the python package manager

Comment: How could there be a standard list of non-standard libraries? Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official website that lists all non-standard Python libraries. However, you can check them up on these following links:

- The Python Package Index (PyPI) is the official package repository
  for Python libraries. It contains both standard and non-standard
  libraries. You can browse PyPI at https://pypi.org/.
- The Awesome Python list is a curated list of Python packages and    resources. It includes both standard and non-standard libraries, as
  well as tools and frameworks. You can find the Awesome Python list at
  https://awesome-python.com/.

Comment: @Who_amI please accept the answer if it helped you get what you wanted. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other suggestions, there is [www.awesomepython.org](https://www.awesomepython.org/) which lists many Python libraries and packages, with an emphasis on data and machine learning.

The libraries are categorised and there is a category specifically for Pandas that you might find useful: [www.awesomepython.org/?c=pandas](https://www.awesomepython.org/?c=pandas)

For full disclosure, I maintain and run this site. It's updated about every week or so.